# Error when trying to verify Monero GUI binary files

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, macos, hash-verification

I'm on https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/verification-allos-advanced.html
I have a problem with creating a new hardware wallet on my Monero GUI (there is NO option to create one) so I thought I'd start at the beginning, download latest software, follow the instructions to verify it.
I installed GnuPG on my Mac (OS 10.15.7)
I attempt to save the page binaryfate.asc but it will only save as a .txt file (binaryfate.asc.txt)
Trying to run the Terminal command given in the instructions, but Terminal can't make sense of it.
So I am stuck at this point.
Can anyone help, who has already been through this process on Mac?
NOTE: I'm not a coder; not a cypherpunk; I can only follow recipe-like instructions.